# Flutter, firebase_admob native admob ads color

Tags: android, flutter, admob, firebase-admob, google-mobile-ads

I'm currently using `firebase_admob` which current is `google_mobile_ads`

and I implemented Native Ads

but do not know how to change the text color or background color or BorderRadius for it

how could I change them?

Answer (score 1):

I realized it has to be done using native code

what a ridiculous...

even "flutter_native_admob"(it is not an official package from google and flutter) supports this feature...

but the official package still needs to change inside the IOS and Android code

so uncomfortable.. one year ago and two years ago.. and still now